# JPA lazy property fetch custome attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm working on a JPA based project and I have two entities say for example Student and School. Each student has one single School.

The Student School attribute fetch type is lazy, yet I need to be able to fetch eagerly only the school name attribute.

is there a way to do this ?

Thank's for respoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using JPA 2.1, you could try an [Entity Graph](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs001.htm), indicating the attributes you want to load:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s")
})
@NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "studentGraph",
        attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "id"),
            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "name"),
            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "school", subgraph = "schoolGraph")
        },
        subgraphs = {
            @NamedSubgraph(
                name = "schoolGraph",
                attributeNodes = {
                    @NamedAttributeNode("name")
                }
            )
        }
    )
})
public class Student {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private School school;
}
```

And use like the following:

```
List<Student> students = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Student.findAll")
    .setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", entityManager.getEntityGraph("studentGraph"))
    .getResultList();
```

Entity Graphs can also be create dynamically.